# Angular + Bootstrap Toggling Radio Buttons

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, toggle

I'm trying to create a set of radio buttons that I want to exhibit toggling behavior (i.e., the selected button should be highlighted). I'm using the following partial template:

```
<h3>{{fullAddress()}}</h3>

<h4 class="control-label">Result of Visit</h4>
<pre>{{visit}}</pre>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="visitState">
    <div ng-repeat="option in visitOptions()" class="btn btn-default" ng-value="option.Value" ng-model="$parent.visit">
        {{option.Label}}
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller is quite simple:

```
app.controller("visitCtrl", function($scope, dataContext) {
    var _visit = "NotHome";

    $scope.visit = "NotHome";

    $scope.visitOptions = function() {
        return dataContext.visitOptions();
    };

    $scope.fullAddress = function() {
        var home = dataContext.home();
        var pin = dataContext.pin();

        if( home.Unit == "" ) return pin.StreetAddress;

        return pin.StreetAddress + " #" + home.Unit;
    };
});
```

dataContext.visitOptions() just returns an array of {Label, Value} objects.

As things stand, there is no toggling behavior. Then again, the model value (visit) doesn't update when you click any of the buttons, either :).

Comment: can you just give us a jsfiddle or plunker

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others, there were two problems with my code:

I was including jQuery, which conflicts with the toggling behavior. I had to remove jQuery and include ui-bootstrap to replace the event-driven functionality bootstrap depends uses.

Tying ng-model to a "root-level" property (i.e., $scope.visit) keeps the auto-updating/two-way data binding functionality of angular from working. I had to tie ng-model to visit.result instead:

```
    $scope.visit = { 
        result: "NotHome",
        hadQuestion: false,
        notes: null,
    };
```

The final markup was pretty simple:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="visitState">
    <div ng-repeat="option in visitOptions()" class="btn btn-primary" btn-radio="option.Value" ng-model="visit.result">
        {{option.Label}}
    </div>
</div>
```